# Python in VS Code: Error when importing module from subfolder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module, subdirectory

I recently started exploring VS Code for developing Python code and I’m running into an issue when I try  to import a module from a subfolder. The exact same code runs perfectly when I execute it in a Jupyter notebook (the subfolders contain the `__init__.py` files etc.) I believe I followed the instructions for setting up the VS Python extension correctly.  Everything else except this one import command works well, but I haven’t been able to figure what exactly is going wrong.

The structure of the project is as follows: The root folder, which is set as the `cwd` contains two subfolders (`src` and `bld`). `src` contains the `py`-file that imports a module that is saved in `foo.py`in the `bld`-folder using `from bld.foo import foo_function`

When running the file, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘bld'`. I have several Anaconda Python environments installed and get the same problem with each of them. When copying `foo.py` to the `src` directory and using `from foo import foo_function` everything works.

My `launch.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${workspaceFolder}/bld"},
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Stefan‘s method worked for me.

Taking as example filesystem:
workspaceFolder/folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/bar.py

I wasn't able to import subfolders like:
`from folder.subfolder1.subfolder2 import bar`
It said: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'`

I added to .vscode/settings.json the following:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

I also added at the beginning of my code:

```
import sys
#[... more imports ...]
sys.path.append(workspaceFolder)
# and then, the subfolder import:
from folder.subfolder1.subfolder2 import bar
```

Now, it works.

Note: all my folders and subfolders have an empty file named `__init__.py`. I still had to do the steps described above.
VSCode version: 1.52.0 (from 10-dec-2020)

Comment: Ok, this explains my problem too. What I now don't get, is why VS code doesn't simply pick the workspaceFolder to add to the sys.path. Instead, it adds the workspaceFolder/folder/subfolder1/subfolder2 to the sys.path, which is useless for package imports. Keep in mind, the current working directory from which the script which is trying to import the module is run could be the workspaceFolder, and VS code STILL doesn't add that folder to sys.path

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally figured out the answer myself: The integrated terminal does not scan the `PYTHONPATH` from the `.env`-file. When running the file in an integrated window, the `PYTHONPATH` is correctly taken from `.env`, however. So in order to run my script in the terminal I had to add the `terminal.integrated.env.*` line in my `settings.json` as follows:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}
```